# Subsequence matching using Regex in JAVA

Tags: java, regex

Suppose I have a string `'classes'`.

Now if I use regex `c.*?s` then it matches `'clas'` in `'classes'` whereas `c.*s` will match `'classes'` in `'classes'`.

But is there a way to form regex which matches all the three subsequence (starting with ***'c'*** and ending with ***'s'***) `'clas'`, `'class'` and `'classes'` in `classes`.

Comment: Try `\bclass?(?:es)?\b`. Please see [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/QyihYP/1). Does it helps?

Comment: Regex alone can't really do this.  You can certainly use the pattern `class.*s` to represent the types of matches you want, but regex cannot _generate_ what those matches would be.

Comment: No, there is no regex in Java that will return *multiple* matches starting at the *same position*.

Comment: @Andreas with due respect I didn't understand your comment. Can you please explain. I'll get some insights too.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen; with due respect I didn't get your **but regex cannot generate what those matches would be** this part. I know that Regular grammars(Type-3) are the generators of regular language and regex are just the representators. Finite automata is the acceptor. But here OP requires only to match a pattern, not generate those. Isn't it? Please correct me if I'm wrong in understanding your intentions.

Comment: @Mandy8055 If the OP _only_ wants to capture `clas`, `class`, and `classes`, then yes, Java's regex can handle it.  If the OP wants to capture all possible `clas.*s`, then there is no way for the engine to know what these matches are.

Comment: Okay @TimBiegeleisen I got your point. I think we can give the regex for starting with some symbol and ending with some symbol over sigma={A,...,Z}. Isn't it? `c(a+b+...+z)*s` which corresponds to `c[a-z]*s` or simply `c.*s`

Comment: I think the OP should clarify its question, rather than we trying to speculate `:-)`

Comment: @Mandy8055 In input string `classes`, OP wants to *find* `clas`, `class`, and `classes`, all 3 starting at index 0. I don't know about other regex engines, but Java's regex engine cannot return all 3 in one execution of a regex `find()` loop. Each result of the `find()` call will return a match with a starting position on or after the ending position of the previous match, and at least one position after the starting position of the previous match (in case of a zero-width match). No two match results will start at the same position.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to find all the subsequence `codeforces` in the string `codeforcesisawesome` which are `codeforces`, `codeforcesis`, `codeforcesisawes` and `codeforcesisawes` using regex.

Comment: Regex alone can't do this, you need to create your own logic/engine to find the substrings.

Comment: Exactly @Andreas. I got your point. Thanks for clarifying.